# How to launch JADE along with Reasoning Engine?

Tags: command-line, java, troubleshooting

I am new to JAVA

I am trying to run Multi Agent Framework (JADE) developed in Java.
I downloaded its binaries from here.
http://jade.tilab.com/dl.php?file=JADE-bin-4.5.0.zip

As per the instruction given in tutorial; I unziped it in C:/Jade.
I have following directory structure there:
Fig: 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0aYA.png)
As per the tutorial I installed Emerald from http://lpis.csd.auth.gr/systems/emerald/resource.html, a resoning engine on C:/Jade. During installation I used Dr-device as an engine. So it created another folder of Dr-Device in Emerald
I have following directory structure there:
Fig: 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAZPV.png)

When I execute following bat file on C:\Jade\Emerald\emerald.bat. It gives me an error that no Jade.boot found.

```
rem @echo off
echo EMERALD 1.0
if EXIST DR-DeviceAgent set dr-device-agent=DR_Reasoner:ReasoningAgent
if EXIST R-DeviceAgent set r-device-agent=R_Reasoner:ReasoningAgent_R
if EXIST SPINdleAgent set spindle-agent=SPINdle_Reasoner:SPINdleAgent
if EXIST ProvaAgent set prova-agent=Prova_Reasoner:provaAgent
java jade.Boot -gui %r-device-agent% %dr-device-agent% %prova-agent% %spindle-agent%
```

I changed last command to:
`java -cp ..\\lib\jade.jar jade.Boot -gui %dr-device-agent%`
because jar file was present somewhere else in directory tree.

It successfully launched Jade framework. But during launch it gave a warning that it was unable to find "ReasoningAgent.class" whereas it is present there as show in following figure
Fig: 3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xndnB.png)

Error in console can be seen in image below(Last 4th and 5th line)
If it was successful in creating an agent reasoner. There must be 4 agents in gui
Fig: 4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft0Xn.png)

Directory Tree:

```
C:\jade>tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 17D4-F630
C.
│   APDescription.txt
│   License
│   MTPs-Main-Container.txt
│   README
│
├───EMERALD
│   │   APDescription.txt
│   │   Basic.class
│   │   BasicJessBehaviour$JessSend.class
│   │   BasicJessBehaviour.class
│   │   EMERALD.bat
│   │   emerald.ico
│   │   ExtendedJessBehaviour.class
│   │   jessAgent.class
│   │   MTPs-Main-Container.txt
│   │   unins000.dat
│   │   unins000.exe
│   │
│   └───DR-DeviceAgent
│           ReasoningAgent$HandleInformBehaviour.class
│           ReasoningAgent.class
│
└───lib
        jade.jar
```

[Update 1]
Thanks, I updated classpath to

```
C:\jade\lib\jade.jar;C:\jade\EMERALD\DR-DeviceAgent;
```

which made last command easier to:

```
java jade.Boot -gui %dr-device-agent%
```

But still problem persists. This same error comes up: SEVERE: Cannot create agent DR_Reasoner: Class ReasoningAgent for agent ( agent- identifier :name DR_Reasoner@192.168.0.119:1099/JADE ) not found - Caused by: ReasoningAgent

Comment: Fix your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I updated classpath which made last command easier to: java jade.Boot -gui %dr-device-agent% . But still problem persists. This same error comes up: SEVERE: Cannot create agent DR_Reasoner: Class ReasoningAgent for agent ( agent-
identifier :name DR_Reasoner@192.168.0.119:1099/JADE ) not found - Caused by:  R
easoningAgent